# Prevent post-install scripts from modifying /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, apt, fstab

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Today I noticed that some script has modified my `/etc/fstab` and commented out the efivars partition:

```
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
# UUID=1562-9EFD  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

This was resulting in an error while installing an update for `grub` as it couldn't find the efivars partition.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Can I somehow limit access to this file, or override some setting in `apt` so that it will never be modified again?

Comment: That is not an efivars mount.  You should correctly understand what your problem is in the first place before asking about the fstab file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try `chattr`

> chattr - change file attributes on a Linux file system

To set attribute :

```
chattr +i file
```

To unset :

```
chattr -i file
```